# How to update UITableView when isEditing property changes?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've currently got a TableViewController with a navigation bar with an editButtonItem. My tableview correctly goes into editing mode when I hit this button, but I want to change the labels on my custom UITableViewCell when isEditing changes. I've tried adding the following into cellForRowAt:

```
   if editingMode {
        cell.timeZoneLabel = ""
    } else {
        cell.timeZoneLabel = timeZone.city
    }
```

But it seems that the tableView isn't reloaded when isEditing changes.

My next thought was to set the following variable at the start:

```
var editingMode = false {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And add the following to viewDidLoad() so I can reload the tableView when isEditing changes:

```
    editingMode = isEditing
```

This doesn't seem to work either though. I've tried searching for other solutions but I can't find anyone having the similar problem.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cell override `didTransition(to`. The `rawValue` 0 represents *normal* state, `rawValue` 1 is `showingEditControl`

```
override func didTransition(to state: UITableViewCell.StateMask) {
    switch state.rawValue {
    case 0: timeZoneLabel = timeZone.city
    case 1: timeZoneLabel = ""
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I've been trying to use this but weirdly it only recognises the default case and case 0, but never case 1. This seems odd as the only code setting edit mode is the editBarButtonItem declaration. Could I be missing something else obvious here?

Comment: I've also tried switching over just the state, with .showingEditControl, but no luck with that either.

Comment: Hm, I tested it quickly and it worked. Insert `print(state)` before the `switch` line to see all states.

Comment: So I just tried that and I get the following: UITableViewCellStateMask(rawValue: 18446744071562067969)
I tried do the same with an example I followed from iOS Programming Big Nerd Ranch (to check if I'd slipped up elsewhere in my app) and I got the same raw value. Any ideas where that might be coming from? On a positive note, when I used that raw value in the switch statement, I can successfully hide the label so thank you!